# Is self signup process available with Google Firebase like it does with AWS Cognito?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, amazon-cognito

I'm looking for out-of-the-box signup and sign-in solution. Based on my research AWS Cognito provides the solution. Custom hosted UI, self-sign-up with configurable required fields.

Does Google Firebase or Google Cloud as a whole have similar functionality? Especially self-sign-up flow with configurable required fields.

I see with Google Firebase email/password authentication provider available for sign-in. but I don't see self sign up process where I can configure the required field during the sign-up process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Authentication is the sign-in solution from Firebase. In addition to SDK for Firebase's supported platforms, it comes with a pre-built UI for the most common platforms: web, Android, iOS and Flutter.

The number of pre-defined fields for a user is quite limited though, see for example the definition here for a [web user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user). There is no way to expand this *within* Firebase Authentication. If you want to store more information for each user, you'll typically do that in one of Firebase's databases (Firestore or Realtime Database) with the user ID as the key for that information.